# Is there an interactive command line environment for Perl?

Tags: perl, read-eval-print-loop

Hi I'm wondering if there is something for Perl similar to Rstudio?  That is to ability to run commands, retain all variables in memory without exiting the script.

For example say I execute this command `my $temp = 83;` then instead of ending the script I change the value `$temp = 22; print "$temp \n";` and so on, but I don't end the script and continue to work on it.  This will be extremely helpful when dealing with a large datasets and general workflow. 
The closest thing I came across is Visual Studio Code using a plugin whereby I can execute specific chunks of code in my script. However I did not find a way to keep the variable persistently in memory.
thanks!

Comment: I use `perl -C -dwE 1` to invoke the interactive Perl debugger, but it's a bit crude. For example, `my $x = 42` won't be remembered on the next line. Drop the `my` and it works.

Answer (score 10):

You want a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

Take a look at [Devel::REPL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::REPL). It brings a script called `re.pl` that you can run.

```
$ re.pl
$ my $foo = 123;
123$ use feature 'say';
$  $foo + 1;
124$
```

A newer alternative is [Reply](https://metacpan.org/pod/Reply) with its `reply` script.

```
$ reply 
0> my $foo = 123;
$res[0] = 123

1> $foo + 2
$res[1] = 125

2>
```

For a comparison, you can [read this blog post](https://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-17/) by Matt Trout.

Comment: Sadly, neither `Devel::REPL` nor `Reply` are under active development. The last stable releases for both are over four years old. This is code rot in action, folks.

Comment: @CecilCurry well volunteered! :) // but to be fair, both of them are stable. You don't always need to keep developing stuff.